# libGDX touchDown difficulties

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm having problems implementing a touchDown commend in my code.
I'm using Iterator to run circles on screen that represents ball texture.
In the code bellow I cut all the unrelated parts to my current problem of removing the ball\circle from the screen when the user touch it. At the moment I call the method bellow in my render and use:

```
    int x1 = Gdx.input.getX();
    int y1 = Gdx.input.getY();
    Vector3 input = new Vector3(x1, y1, 0);
    cam.unproject(input);
```

And use the "input" as the parameter for the "ballsIterator(input);". The problem is that I was told that for the touch effect to stop I need to use the code inside the touchDown method. But how can I do it? The full version of the method bellow I have to put in the render method regardless of having a touch down effect, and I tried implementing InputProcessor and repeating the method's code in the touchDown method but without calling it in the render method, and so it didn't work, and when I tried to call it inside the render I didn't know what parameters to use for the "int pointer, int button"...
Question is, after all of the above, how can I use the touchDown method in my code?

```
private void ballsIterator(Vector3 input){
    Iterator<Circle> iterBall = balls.iterator();
    while (iterBall.hasNext()) {
        Circle ball = iterBall.next();
        if (dog.velocity.x != 0) {

            if (ball.contains(input.x, input.y)) {
                iterMeteor.remove();
            }
        } else {
            iterMeteor.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Store a `Vector3 touchPos` and set it in `touchDown`: `touchPos = cam.unproject(new Vector3(screenX, screeny, 0))`. In `touchUp` simply set it to `null` and in `render` you can say `if (touchPos != null) ballsIterator(touchPos);`

Comment: Deleted my previews comments since I played around, following your explanation and managed to achieve what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: If you solved your problem you can post the solution as an answer and accept it, it may help others with the same problem.

Comment: I would but since I'm still learning my project is a bit of a mess and most of its structure based on Kilobolt's Zombie Bird tutorial.

Comment: Just write, what exactly solved the problem you are describing here and i guess it should be enough, code is not really needed or just some kind of pseudo code, like in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Springbua explanations I managed to solve my problem by dividing the Iterator method. Repeating the necessary part and copied the code that responsible for the click to a new public static void method with Vector3 as a parameter, and in the class that implement InputProcessor I created a Vector3, gave it the touchDown parameters, called the new Iterator method that hold the click part and used the InputProcessor class's Vector3 as its parameter.